# Custom iteration for SplObjectStorage

Tags: php, spl, splobjectstorage

I want to modify the way to iterate an SPLObjectStorage object, such as sorting it first by the data (info).

So, in a loop, it goes numerically from a to z (using sort() function)

But, in SPLObjectStorage, there is no access to the array, right ?

Is it possible to do it since we don't have the access to the array of objects ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Internally `SplobjectStorage` use the same data structure as an array (the `HashTable`), but it's not an "array-array" as we know from the PHP userland: we only add values and not keys, as keys are actually generated from the values by hashing them (you can even overwrite this by overwriting the `getHash` method). Another difference is that you can additionally add information to the object.

In short, SplObjectStorage should not be used as an array, but as either a set or a map, there lies its strength.